# C++ System Call Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Hello I am trying to write a program that will create a thread in which it will system call the char buffer. I am new to threads and I am having a hard time to get the thread working.
Most of this stuff I got is from just searching in gooogle and watching videos.

Here is what I have so far.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 25

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID param);

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        DWORD threadID;
        HANDLE ThreadHandle;

        fgets(buffer,BUFFERSIZE,stdin);

        if (buffer == "dir")
        {
            ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0,ThreadFunc, &buffer, 0, &threadID);
        }
        else if (buffer == "help")
        {

        }
        else if (buffer == "vol")
        {

        }
        else if (buffer == "path")
        {

        }
        else if (buffer == "tasklist")
        {

        }
        else if (buffer == "notepad")
        {

        }
        else if (buffer == "echo")
        {

        }
        else if (buffer == "color")
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID param)
{
    char* value = (char*)param;
    system(value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There appears to be some critical information that's missing from your question. That would be an actual, specific question.

Comment: What more information needed? I want to know why the tread is not being accessed from the createtread call. If this is ran `system(fgets(buffer,BUFFERSIZE,stdin));` the system call works, but not from the `ThreadFunc`

Comment: Most likely because `buffer` is instantiated in automatic scope, and by the time the new thread gets to the `system()` call, the loop in the parent thread has terminated, destroying the `buffer`. You do understand that `buffer` is instantiated in automatic scope, which means that it gets destroyed at the end of the scope, at the end of the loop, before the loop runs again. This is fundamental C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your code:

  1. As Daniel pointed out, incorrect parameter to
  `CreateThread`
  (buffer). You use wrong type and scope of the variable.

  2. Expressions in your if statements will be always evaluated to false. Types like
  `char *`
  don't have overloaded operators and
  `==`
  will result to pointer comparison.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 25

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID param);

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        char* buffer = new char [BUFFERSIZE];
        DWORD threadID;
        HANDLE ThreadHandle;

        fgets(buffer,BUFFERSIZE,stdin);

        if (strcmp(buffer, "dir") == 0)
        {
            ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0,ThreadFunc, buffer, 0, &threadID);
        }
        else if(...) // next
        {
        }
        else
        {
            delete[] buffer;
        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID param)
{
    char* value = (char*)param;
    system(value);
    delete[] value;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two mistakes:

**First**

```
ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0,ThreadFunc, &buffer, 0, &threadID)
```

Should be

```
ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0,ThreadFunc, buffer, 0, &threadID)
```

Notice that the buffer lost it's `&` since the name of an array is already a pointer to it.

**Second**

Your main thread exits right after running the second thread.
Sadly, as soon as the main thread exists the process is terminated, so nothing happens. Try adding a sleep in your main thread.